# Can I use a wireless router on an existing wireless network to make a wired connection to a computer?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, repeater

Its a [Netgear WNDR4300](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-routers/wndr4300.aspx), I don't see anything mentioning bridged mode anywhere. I would like it just temporarily connect it to a computer, but I might have to  put some other firmware on the router to do this.

The modem/router im trying to bridge from is a ZyXEL PK5001Z

According to the manual, "Set up both units with the same wireless settings (SSID, mode, channel, and security). 
The wireless security option must be set to None or WEP." lol.. no, I can't do this.

Comment: Do you perhaps already have an *existing* wireless network to which you want to connect this Netgear WNDR4300 in order to connect a wired computer? If so, you're on the right track with the term "bridge" but what you actually need is a wireless to Ethernet bridge, not a wireless router.

Comment: Yes, Twisty is right, I'm trying to connect a wired computer to an existing wireless network.

Comment: @ParadigmArchitect and to do that you want Wireless Repeater Mode as indicated in my answer that I don't think you understood.

Answer (score 4):

See Page 91 of the [manual](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/WNDR4300/WNDR4300_UM_23Sept2014.pdf).   It seems the mode you are looking for is wireless repeater mode, which also enables the wired LAN ports.

FYI, with a standard AP (instead of a full router) this is often called "client mode".  Allowing the AP to connect to a network and providing a hardwire network connection.

Comment: Yes thanks, 1 page manual I got with it covered the WPS button very well, thanks for the link!